# FCM notification unsubscribe

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase cloud messaging in my app for push notifications. Everything working fine. But notifications are getting even user logged out from app. If user uninstalled the app directly then how can i unsubscribe the topic notification. if i have subscribe the a topic and now i unsubscribe the topic and subscribe the new topic then i also receiving notification for old subscribe topic also.

Comment: Note: You can subscribe up to 1,000 devices in a single request. If you provide an array with over 1,000 registration tokens, the request will fail with a messaging/invalid-argument error. any one can explain this

read from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/manage-topic-subscriptions

Comment: Note: You can unsubscribe up to 1,000 devices in a single request. If you provide an array with over 1,000 registration tokens, the request will fail with a messaging/invalid-argument error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you uninstall the app, the service handling the FCM messages and notifications will also be removed from the device. So you won't be receiving any push notifications once you uninstall.

Comment: yes in case of unsubscribe its acceptable but getting issues here if i have subscribe the a topic and now i unsubscribe the topic and subscribe the new topic then i also receiving notification for old subscribe topic also.

Comment: Can you post the code? Maybe there is a mistake in the flow.

Comment: if(isNotificationOn) {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(Constants.NOTIFCATION_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC);
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(Constants.NOTIFCATION_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC+ AppPreferenceManager.getUserGroupId(getActivity()));
        }      else {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Constants.NOTIFCATION_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC);
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Constants.NOTIFCATION_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC + AppPreferenceManager.getUserGroupId(getActivity()));
        }

Comment: how is the value of **isNotificationOn** set?

Comment: it's is flag on switch button for subscribe and unsubscribe the notification and it;s value store in database

Comment: Are you receiving notifications for the old topic alone or the new topic too?

Comment: yes i have receive notification from old topic also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185546/discussion-between-charan-m-and-imran-khan).

Answer (score 1):

if your are subscribing to fcm topic then there is way to unsubscribe from that topic to not recieve any notifications for that topic.

below is the method you need :

unsubscribeFromTopic (String topic)

check google firebase docs here  :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging

Comment: Note: You can unsubscribe up to 1,000 devices in a single request. If you provide an array with over 1,000 registration tokens, the request will fail with a messaging/invalid-argument error. all are not unsubscribe , devices still get notification for that topic

Comment: @Imrankhan okay, then send unsubscribe request in buch of 1000 request. create   list to send in first bunch send 1000 in second bunch send another 1000 dont send at once.

Comment: it's will be difficult to Millions user

Comment: @Imrankhan millions users going to uninstall app at the same time?

Comment: yes my all app user don't receive message and user which unsubscribe the topic notification , but they also receive message